# Is this right way to use php oop and mysqli?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I am not very experienced in php oop. Moreover, when mysqli comes with php oop, it make me more confused about using it in best efficient way. Anyway, first look at my connection class:

```
<?php
//connectionclass.php
class connection{
public $conn;
public $warn;
public $err;

function __construct(){
  $this->connect();
}

private function connect(){
  $this->conn = @ new mysqli('localhost', 'sever_user', 'user_password');
    if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
      $this->conn = FALSE;
      $this->warn = '<br />Failed to connect database! Please try again later';
     }
}

public function get_data($qry){
  $result = $this->conn->query($qry);
  if($result->num_rows>=1){
    return $result;
  }else{
    $this->err = $this->conn->error;
    return FALSE;
  }
  $result->free();
}

public function post_data($qry){
  $this->conn->query($qry);
  if($this->conn->affected_rows>=1){
    return TRUE;
  }else{
    $this->err = $this->conn->error;
    return FALSE;
  }
}
}
?>
```

Now please structure of a php page which uses mysql database to store and get data:

```
<?php
//login.php
include('/include/connectionclass.php');
$db = new connection();

$query = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE user_country='India'";
$data = $db->get_data($query);
  if($data){
    while($row=$data->fetch_assoc()){
      echo 'User Name: ':.$row["user_name"].' Age: '.$row["age"];
    }
  }
?>
```

So my login.php uses connection class to get data about users. All the things are running well. But one things made me confused. In connectionclass.php `$this->conn` is itself an object as it calls `new mysqli`. So this is an object inside another object `$db`. Moreover, When I am using `$data = $db->get_data($query);`, a result set is created inside object `$db` by method `get_data`, then this result set is copied into a variable `$data` inside login.php page.

So according to me, actually two result sets/data sets are creating here, one inside db object and one inside login page. Is it right way to use mysqli and php to get dataset from mysql database? Will it use more memory and server resources when the dataset is larger (when have to get large amount of data for many users)?

If it is not right way, please explain your points and please give me code which can be used efficiently for php oop and mysqli.

Comment: This question qualifies for the codereview.stackexchange.com. And no, this is not the right way to use php oop and mysqli. Even though only one result set is created.

Comment: Thanks for your nice comment. But I don't know how to post in codereview as I have no account in codereview.stackexchange.com. Do I need to create another account for that or the existing will enough to post this code there?

Comment: Yes, existing is enough. this is a single network that can link all your accounts.

Comment: Thanks. I already have posted this question to codereview.  I did not know about codereview before. Thanks again for your information and suggestion. Hope you will give me sample code there (in codereview) which can be best alternative of my code to use php oop and mysqli efficiently. The link in codereview for same post is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129088/is-this-right-way-to-use-php-oop-and-mysqli